# ListView with scale animation isn't smooth

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

When the list has only one row, with only a TextView it's being animated smoothly, the problem starts when the list is beginning to be heavier, as I load it with more row's, each row contains an ImageView.

I used my own animation, though i tried the more simple way with XML's, and it doesn't preform any better.

this is the animation:

```
    public Animation slidePaneAnim2 (final Context context,
        final View view,
        final int maxHeight,
        final boolean openORclose ){

    /** Create new Slide Pane animation */
    Animation anim = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            int newHeight;
            int initHeight=200;

            if (openORclose) {
                //In case we want to open pane
                newHeight = initHeight + (int) (maxHeight * interpolatedTime);
            } else {
                //In case we want to close pane
                newHeight = initHeight + (int) (maxHeight * (1-interpolatedTime));
            }
            //Apply new params
            view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
            view.requestLayout();
        }
        ...
    };
  return anim;
}
```

Does anyone know how to make it smoother?

Comment: The problem is with your `Animation`, you are calling `requestLayout` in `applyTransform` which is very bad for performance.

Comment: Use NineOldAndroid animation library and you will see the difference. It is similar to built in new animation framework but has support for older Android versions as well. http://nineoldandroids.com/

Comment: Thank M-WaJeEh, it's a great library, works like magic!